# Write markdown using markdown

Tags: github, markdown

I was trying to write some markdown code using markdown in github, but it always leads to some strange format, is there any idea about this issue?

For example: I wanna

```
# header1 #
```

but it always display as real header

## header1

and it also happens to code block, i wanna

````
```ruby
require 'redcarpet'
markdown = Redcarpet.new("Hello World!")
puts markdown.to_html
```
````

but I got

```
require 'redcarpet'
markdown = Redcarpet.new("Hello World!")
puts markdown.to_html
```

that is so confusing. Is there a good way to write it in markdown?

Comment: Your content is hilariously messed up... You know, asking for Markdown help on a site that uses Markdown in completely broken Markdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape characters like <kbd>#</kbd> or <kbd>_</kbd> in Markdown with a backslash. For example:

> \# header 1

If you look at the source code of this post, you'll actually notice that I had to escape the escape character so that the backslash would display in the answer, but a single backslash is all you need to have a special character rendered literally.

You can also use pre-formatted code blocks by indenting your text 4 spaces. For example:

```
    # header 1
```

Again,if you look at the source you'll see I actually indented 8 spaces so that the code block shows 4 space characters. However, indenting by 4 spaces is generally all you need to display your Markdown source, unless you're trying to be very meta with your rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Another tip is simply to wrap your markdown code in `<pre></pre>` (that avoids the need to add 4 spaces at the beginning of each line)

`````
# tilte
```` ruby
code
````
`````

Answer (score 0):

You can use backslash to escape Markdown syntax.
Just put it in the beginning of the line.
Just try [Markdown editor](https://markdown-editor.github.io/) online and you will simply see how it works.